# Why can one MySQL transaction see modifications made in another transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions, isolation-level

From the documentation of MySQL [transactions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) and [isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_isolation_level) I seem to understand that the following PHPunit test code should succeed. However, it does not. In short: it seems that `$pdo2` can see changes made by `$pdo`. The test code:

```
        $pdo->exec('CREATE TABLE my_table (id INT(10) UNSIGNED, a INT(10), b INT(10), PRIMARY KEY (id))');
        $pdo->exec("INSERT INTO my_table VALUES (1, 12, 13), (2, 22, 23)");

        // Or just ->beginTransaction()
        $pdo->exec('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ');
        $pdo2->exec('SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ');
        $pdo->exec('START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT');
        $pdo2->exec('START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT');

        // Start consistent read in both transactions
        $this->select($pdo, 'SELECT * FROM my_table');
        $this->select($pdo2, 'SELECT * FROM my_table');

        // Update in first transaction
        $pdo->exec('UPDATE my_table SET a = 6 WHERE id = 1');
        $this->assertSame([
            ['id' => 1, 'a' => 6, 'b' => 13],
            ['id' => 2, 'a' => 22, 'b' => 23],
        ], $this->select($pdo, 'SELECT * FROM my_table'));
        $pdo->exec('COMMIT'); // or just ->commit()

        // Update in second transaction
        $pdo2->exec('UPDATE my_table SET b = 8 WHERE id = 1');
        $this->assertSame([
            ['id' => 1, 'a' => 12, 'b' => 8],
            ['id' => 2, 'a' => 22, 'b' => 23],
        ], $this->select($pdo2, 'SELECT * FROM my_table'));
        $pdo2->exec('COMMIT'); // or just ->commit()

        $this->assertSame([
            ['id' => 1, 'a' => 6, 'b' => 8],
            ['id' => 2, 'a' => 22, 'b' => 23],
        ], $this->select($pdo, 'SELECT * FROM my_table'));

        $this->assertSame([
            ['id' => 1, 'a' => 6, 'b' => 8],
            ['id' => 2, 'a' => 22, 'b' => 23],
        ], $this->select($pdo2, 'SELECT * FROM my_table'));
```

(`select()` and `$pdo` are given at the bottom.)

When performing this in a phpunit test, it fails with the following message on the second `assertSame()`:

```
Failed asserting that two arrays are identical.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
 Array &0 (
     0 => Array &1 (
         'id' => 1
-        'a' => 12
+        'a' => 6
         'b' => 8
     )
     1 => Array &2 (
```

So, this leads me to believe that `$pdo2` does see the changes of `$pdo` despite both transactions having been started before any `UPDATE`s take place. I have tested with starting transactions like above with `exec()` and using `pdo->beginTransaction()`, both with MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2. From the above mentioned documentation page on transactions (specifically the section on `WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT`) I understand that my phpunit test should succeed, at least when `REPEATABLE READ` is used as I do (and which should be the default). As I understand it, the actual behaviour I see here should fit better with the description of `READ COMMITTED`.

**Why does this sequence of queries not behave as I would expect?**

Auxiliary functions:

```
public function select(\PDO $pdo, string $query, array $params = [])
{
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute($params);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}

// $pdo and $pdo2 are instantiated as follows: (so, 2 separate connections)
    new PDO(
        'mysql:host=mysql-server;dbname=my_db;charset=utf8mb4',
        'username',
        'secret',
        [
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
            PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        ]
    );
```